# parameterised postgresql select statement using python

Tags: python, postgresql, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

```
sql="select %s,tablename from pg_table_def where tablename like (%s)"

data=("schemaname","abc",)

cur.execute(sql,data)
```

If I pass a value as described above, then the select takes it as a string.
Which is not the intention.

If I try

```
data=(schemaname,"abc",)
```

then it shows the error `global name 'schemaname' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot parameterize object name (in this case, a column name) that way. You could instead resort to string manipulation:

```
column = "schemaname"
sql = "select {}, tablename from pg_table_def where tablename like (%s)".format(column) 
data= ("abc",)

cur.execute(sql,data)
```